# render array values from one page to another

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-mobile, foreach

Hi I get with my file `chatmain.php` some values from a mysql database. for every new row should created a new `<li>` element. If the user click on this element he becomes redirected to the page `chatview`. `chatview` need the values of the clicked list item. How can I get the corresponding row values ,after clicking a list item, in `chatview`?

**main page:**

```
 <div class="ui-page" data-role="page" id="main">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <?php
            include("chatmain.php");
            ?>
            <ul data-role="listview" id="uItem" data-inset="true">
            <?php foreach ($result2 as $keyres2 => $rowres2): ?>

                <li><a href="#chatview">user<?php echo $rowres2['id']; ?></a></li>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    </div>        
    </div>
```

**chatview page:**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="chatview">    

    <div data-role="content">

    </div><!-- div content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By clicking I suppose that you are refering to a link, so you can just use GET attribute to determine the concerned message id.

If the request is done via jQuery, just add an id element with the id of your message to each li and send it as a variable through the Ajax Request.

In both way, you just have to retrieve $_GET['id'] to get the right identifier and creating your function as you wanted to.

Comment: Ok, but where and how should I write $_GET['id'] that the php script know from which element it should get the id?

Comment: Do you know PHP ? You should use WHERE in your SQL request to only retrieve the concerned element according to the parameter you got as an is

Comment: Oh ok, I didnt thought that thats enough ;)